# Firebase push notification read/unread state detection

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project that we integrated Firebase push notification for personalized user notifications. I am looking for a solution to check read and unread state of a notification message rather than handling in the app server side (each user keeping a state of the notification in the table) is there a way to detect it in the Firebase level ?  Short and sweet is there a way to detect read and unread state of a notification message with Firebase?

Comment: There is no way to know if a user has read a notification, all that has to be handled by your app. The only thing you can know is if it your request to google to send the push was successful

Comment: @tyczj Thanks for your response do you have nay suggestion about the best way of doing that rather than putting more pressure  on the db and server

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda you can try IBM Bluemix Push Notification to track Message status.. https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/index.html

Comment: There is no fool proof way to get the status of the notification, the user does not have to click on the notification and can just dismiss it. without knowing what you are doing and why you need this its hard to suggest anything

Comment: @tyczj thanks mate